# How do I create mail.example.com with postfix and dovecot?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, postfix, domain, dovecot

I currently have `postfix` and `dovecot` installed on my Ubuntu VPS. While I can log in via a mail client like `thunderbird` with the IP, it would be nice to have `mail.example.com`. I already own a domain with an MX record, so mail can be sent to my VPS, but how can I create the `mail` subdomain? I currently use cloudflare, so specific instructions for that would be appreciated. I'm good with Ubuntu and bash, but I suck at networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a sub domain in you domain provider. if you domain is already pointed to IP by A record 
you can point C name with mail server IP (x.x.x.x)

```
mail.example.com x.x.x.x
```

Or else add a A record with mail server IP (x.x.x.x) and also add above cname

and setup webmail such as SquirrelMail
https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/

for clouldflare if you are using you own mx you can stay with that.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218069617-How-do-I-add-or-edit-mail-or-MX-records-

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168876-My-email-or-mail-stopped-working-What-should-I-do-

ps you will have to add cnames/A records by cloudflare dns if your dns is managed by cloudflare.

Comment: I did that, and dig and ping find my server ip when I test mail.example.com, but dovecot and postfix refuse to authenticate unless I use the direct IP

Comment: in cloud flare bypass mx record to use direct ip  and use Cname/A record in your domain settings control panel .. postfix may have difficulty with cloudflare shared ips if you use them as mx or A record. I think default cloudflare comes with mx bypass settings on. use A record with postfix that you have already set at domain provider

Comment: Nevermind, a simple iPhone reboot resolved the domain issue.